# publishing an immediate update

Tags: android, google-play, publish, in-app-update

While publishing new version of app in google play, is there any way immediate(force) update for all users?I cant find information about publishing immediate update.For example I published app with wrong code.I want to force update users to new update

Comment: You can learn about in-app updates, it provides you the ability to publish new version of app and then force the user to update to continue using the app via the immediate in-app update option. See https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates.

Comment: @Phantômaxx I checked there.There are all information about handling update.Not about to publish

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your app versions data with version code at your server and match it for updates. Maintain statuses at the server and use accordingly the update statuses. You can use an API call at your server.

Or you can implement this in your app [In-app-updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)

I prefer API call as it can force the user to update the application from play store.